# Is there a way to get at the end of the test how many times an assertion fired (failed)

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am not using uvm or ovm, thus can't use their fancy report system .
I would like to know if there is a simple way to know how many times a particular assertion fired during a test or alternatively how many times $error was invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I ended with, not sure if it's the best way/solution , but it works.
I defined a systemverilog package that contains assertion error counter, and incremented this counter in the action block of each assertion.
example code below:

```
package assertion_error;
   int assertion_fails;
endpackage : assertion_error

assert property (a1) 
else begin
        assertion_error::assertion_fails += 1; 
end
```